# Jquery select target of href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to select the element which is the target of a href. I have procedurally generated links which point to corresponding elements on the same page. Is there any way to select the element that is being linked to?

```
<a href="#ref1">1</a>
<a href="#ref2">1</a>
<a href="#ref3">1</a>

<p id="ref1>
<p id="ref2>
<p id="ref3>
```

Sorry if this was a little unclear, though the two top answers were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: First off, what have you tried? More importantly though, what do you mean? How do you want to select them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.attr()` to grab the `href` and since it has a hash thats all you need to select the `p` tag with the corresponding `id`

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var selectedLink = $(this).attr("href");
  $(selectedLink).html("SELECTED"); //just for example

});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld4jrfcv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want

```
$("a").click(function() {
   var target = $(this).attr("href");
   var obj = $(target); // here is what you want
   alert(obj.attr(id));
});
```

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/wfs1qxrx/)

Comment: `click` not `onclick` ...

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea of adding the click event, getting the hash, and selecting the element with that id.

```js
$("#links").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  var hash = this.hash;
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(hash).addClass("selected");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
p.selected {
   outline: 1px dashed black;  
}

a.selected {
   font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
<a href="#ref1">1</a>
<a href="#ref2">2</a>
<a href="#ref3">3</a>
</div>
  
<p id="ref1">a</p>
<p id="ref2">b</p>
<p id="ref3">c</p>
```